# iPhone app crashes on first run/install (apns?) but ok after... logs attached

Tags: iphone, ios, crash, installation

My app crashes the very first time it runs/installs. After that it's fine. It also appears that this issue resolved itself with iOS. I'm currently working on an update and it would be great to have it at 100% health.

Here's the crash log

Although I'm getting my head around obj-c slowly crash logs are still Martian to me – any helpful pointers please (pun intended).

```
Incident Identifier: 142E153B-0885-4775-A554-2D74DB4EE3E3
CrashReporter Key:   d7848ba3b41e11c0a632dbd2e03a125c438a70d7
Hardware Model:      iPod2,1
Process:         MYAPP [331]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/1D041F34-447C-47BB-BCF9-E8A9D3C4FDBC/MYAPP.app/MYAPP
Identifier:      MYAPP
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-11-18 14:47:44.892 +0000
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.2.1 (8C148)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00000001
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x30183f1c objc_msgSend + 16
1   Foundation                      0x33fbf230 _NSDescriptionWithLocaleFunc + 30
2   CoreFoundation                  0x35e837ca __CFStringAppendFormatCore + 5518
3   CoreFoundation                  0x35e82208 _CFStringCreateWithFormatAndArgumentsAux + 68
4   CoreFoundation                  0x35e9fa26 _CFLogvEx + 70
5   Foundation                      0x33fc0210 NSLogv + 58
6   Foundation                      0x33fc01c6 NSLog + 18
7   MYAPP                           0x0001edda 0x1000 + 122330
8   UIKit                           0x3386cfd0 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1108
9   UIKit                           0x33866a70 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 388
10  UIKit                           0x338202dc -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1468
11  UIKit                           0x3381fb14 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 60
12  UIKit                           0x3381f3ac _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6816
13  GraphicsServices                0x35262c80 PurpleEventCallback + 1040
14  CoreFoundation                  0x35e9a5c4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 22
15  CoreFoundation                  0x35e9a582 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 158
16  CoreFoundation                  0x35e8c82e __CFRunLoopRun + 574
17  CoreFoundation                  0x35e8c504 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 220
18  CoreFoundation                  0x35e8c412 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 54
19  UIKit                           0x3386554c -[UIApplication _run] + 540
20  UIKit                           0x33862550 UIApplicationMain + 964
21  MYAPP                           0x00002c8e 0x1000 + 7310
22  MYAPP                           0x00002c58 0x1000 + 7256

Thread 1:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x32cd1974 kevent + 24
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x32da02fc _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 88
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x32d9fd68 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 96
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x32d9f788 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 120
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x32d28970 _pthread_wqthread + 392
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x32d1f2fc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x32d292fc __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x32d28b50 _pthread_wqthread + 872
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x32d1f2fc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x32c9d3b0 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x32c9f894 mach_msg + 60
2   CoreFoundation                  0x35e8cf7c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x35e8c780 __CFRunLoopRun + 400
4   CoreFoundation                  0x35e8c504 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 220
5   CoreFoundation                  0x35e8c412 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 54
6   WebCore                         0x369e7d14 RunWebThread(void*) + 524
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x32d27b44 _pthread_start + 364
8   libSystem.B.dylib               0x32d197a4 thread_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000001    r1: 0x33c278ef      r2: 0x35f49a2c      r3: 0x0000000c
    r4: 0x00000001    r5: 0x35f49a2c      r6: 0x00000000      r7: 0x2fdfd424
    r8: 0x00000054    r9: 0x2fdfd3c4     r10: 0x2fdfd5ae     r11: 0x2fdfd594
    ip: 0x3e44e568    sp: 0x2fdfd408      lr: 0x33fbf237      pc: 0x30183f1c
  cpsr: 0x000f0010

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -    0x53fff +MYAPP armv6  <cecbc9b876193bed85a9048b0ef16cc8> /var/mobile/Applications/1D041F34-447C-47BB-BCF9-E8A9D3C4FDBC/PwC UK.app/PwC UK
   0xed000 -    0xeefff  dns.so armv6  <88b569311cca4a9593b2d670051860d1> /usr/lib/info/dns.so
0x2fe00000 - 0x2fe29fff  dyld armv6  <617f6daf4103547c47a8407a2e0b90de> /usr/lib/dyld
0x30180000 - 0x30247fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv6  <429841269f8bcecd4ba3264a8725dad6> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x30248000 - 0x30356fff  CFNetwork armv6  <d6eeee83216ee9c553134f069f37cbc2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x30359000 - 0x3037afff  libRIP.A.dylib armv6  <22c6da37f3adf325f99c3a0494e04c02> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x3037b000 - 0x3037efff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv6  <bed95ed187350ce27d22ed241ef892ea> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x303e6000 - 0x3059cfff  AudioToolbox armv6  <bb65e8ed531fe5923eb8ac00a7c0d87d> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x305a2000 - 0x306fffff  libGLProgrammability.dylib armv6  <aec6b54ffd532bb607aab4acbab679b6> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLProgrammability.dylib
0x3076a000 - 0x30770fff  MBX2D armv6  <fad4955cab36e0179df6f8f27d365b8f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MBX2D.framework/MBX2D
0x3077c000 - 0x307f4fff  EventKit armv6  <c1fb82d645d3bf1f2e0558cc884712e9> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
0x30859000 - 0x30866fff  CoreVideo armv6  <7b100fd5fdf98db1cd0f0649e7f6f316> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x3089e000 - 0x308a3fff  CaptiveNetwork armv6  <f41df4b358b77b29ff85e0eaea88ee1d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x308a4000 - 0x30965fff  AddressBookUI armv6  <fea72732451610277e22a667d35ad76d> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x309a9000 - 0x309c9fff  AppleAccount armv6  <0ef3f6564414f3ef030031ae25b28bbd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
0x309d7000 - 0x309d8fff  DataMigration armv6  <d2de7c0db77278484236669c2cdccabb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x30adb000 - 0x30b1efff  CoreTelephony armv6  <cabbce0fa7630065dc7e7d3ca3bc616c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x32c9c000 - 0x32ddafff  libSystem.B.dylib armv6  <70571c1e697e2ae7f7a9b1a499453bb6> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x32ddb000 - 0x32ea5fff  Celestial armv6  <11172a6ee53bdf067548cd4496bc5fe0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x32ee6000 - 0x32f42fff  libGLImage.dylib armv6  <7c1049f20c4e64591c09d3ac00c7d3ab> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x33035000 - 0x33035fff  vecLib armv6  <8f914b3e8a581d49fb21d2c0ff75be03> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x3319f000 - 0x331a7fff  ProtocolBuffer armv6  <8ed6e560e85eecfaf625219a8247aea4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x331fc000 - 0x331fffff  MobileInstallation armv6  <456ed7fe6dd9fcd8e78df425085b1452> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x33201000 - 0x3320cfff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv6  <6aa8a4ed0906a495d059ace9125f525d> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x33268000 - 0x3326dfff  IOSurface armv6  <ffd66ca04dfe7d382d6961f0df3839ff> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x3326e000 - 0x33273fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv6  <bd1c480607cc286288db1ca1aec64180> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x33274000 - 0x33276fff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv6  <f42bbbf67195a7b98d67ad021bba4784> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x3328b000 - 0x3328cfff  CoreSurface armv6  <5e290514380c626e9b0f9f9985b9dc7a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x3330c000 - 0x33317fff  MobileWiFi armv6  <c7532e63e083a1dd2a0ef7352b85749d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x3337a000 - 0x3337efff  ApplePushService armv6  <0560b630d26e261e205fc58942e1885c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x3337f000 - 0x3337ffff  Accelerate armv6  <cdde24a7ad004b2b2e600cd4f3ac5eb7> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x33417000 - 0x33476fff  CoreAudio armv6  <ccc4bace0d6eca79a32ed84d566f72e9> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x33477000 - 0x3348dfff  PersistentConnection armv6  <006723906b8ac250c1681a1821fbe94d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x33490000 - 0x33494fff  CertUI armv6  <57c499baf9d343a78fe1b43f0f3ef997> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x334a1000 - 0x334e5fff  AddressBook armv6  <1f30c3370dad27331a491ba4b190813c> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x334e6000 - 0x33505fff  EAP8021X armv6  <fa56845b5396c3ebb368c2368331643c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x3358f000 - 0x335fffff  libsqlite3.dylib armv6  <87b9bb47687902d9120d03d1da9eb9fc> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x33600000 - 0x33605fff  AssetsLibraryServices armv6  <224b3cf992a01814f91481244e3213eb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x33620000 - 0x33627fff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv6  <de9b417e7278742e90b30b1ad45f31fa> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x3362d000 - 0x33671fff  VideoToolbox armv6  <101dbbcd34cc3231a8be3fd6392556aa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x337c7000 - 0x3381afff  IOKit armv6  <20da5e822f21a8d0a7c5b3e149330efd> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x3381b000 - 0x33c97fff  UIKit armv6  <14ec6c926b8bda71b73136f6e1a6ac1b> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x33ced000 - 0x33d0bfff  libresolv.9.dylib armv6  <9c94634beea733e754dc115737b6e63c> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x33d0c000 - 0x33e14fff  CoreData armv6  <6e3af4b4648ae695f8d4bc0bf5a9dba5> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x33e15000 - 0x33f9cfff  CoreGraphics armv6  <9a1d72fa9549d83abc1e735ba37a4dc2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x33fb3000 - 0x340d4fff  Foundation armv6  <6bdeb19a1fcb93e2930dadb50416f881> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x340d5000 - 0x340e8fff  libmis.dylib armv6  <dba9c086b49bd9540930ff27211570d6> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x340ea000 - 0x340edfff  libAccessibility.dylib armv6  <74e0f77cc276a9412be268c795fdcbca> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x341bc000 - 0x34389fff  MediaToolbox armv6  <21ceabd0e5de17ad4e883c85fcd34d51> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x3438c000 - 0x3439ffff  Notes armv6  <acf9e548948ecb299270c8398ef297a1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes
0x343a0000 - 0x343fafff  MessageUI armv6  <21bb9d93911f7015b79aef9dc6df55ef> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
0x343fb000 - 0x3449afff  ProofReader armv6  <2734920b62f174c17aeeb15f371615ef> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x3449b000 - 0x344a7fff  libkxld.dylib armv6  <f74f359de7bbe3ccdc37fa6f332aebf4> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
0x344a8000 - 0x344f1fff  CoreLocation armv6  <a69399375024b2bfae8bb96e845f4fd0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x346d1000 - 0x346dbfff  AccountSettings armv6  <eca67ab04f724e1fa7c6406c88e75433> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x346dc000 - 0x347c8fff  QuartzCore armv6  <77cd91ff21fe6c58c309f2c82eb95ca5> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x347f5000 - 0x34801fff  SpringBoardServices armv6  <fd0c472436b3306f5b56118c93c8a423> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x34879000 - 0x34884fff  ITSync armv6  <a451205e89373cbdf0832688085e8f72> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ITSync.framework/ITSync
0x34885000 - 0x348c7fff  ManagedConfiguration armv6  <397723a33c19c3487d304d69580acbfc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x348c8000 - 0x348cbfff  CrashReporterSupport armv6  <00bc60f690e6328b64e7a7b718edf45a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x349b3000 - 0x34a9cfff  MapKit armv6  <d28b96a0107a7822fda677ed28901c0c> /System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/MapKit
0x34b0f000 - 0x34edcfff  libLAPACK.dylib armv6  <0eb734c91165416224b98c943ff6476b> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x34ef3000 - 0x34fcffff  WebKit armv6  <83da207070be989ba81dba3a83d5206a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x34ff2000 - 0x35001fff  OpenGLES armv6  <37eda5ddcff210dd321157da35a87a5e> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x35074000 - 0x3518bfff  libicucore.A.dylib armv6  <8968ff3f62d7780bb1bd75026a7628d0> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x35196000 - 0x351c1fff  MobileSync armv6  <b42cf746d993e6765d432edf47987835> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSync.framework/MobileSync
0x35220000 - 0x35234fff  MobileDeviceLink armv6  <19d66078f8cf19be558713c13612c7a3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDeviceLink.framework/MobileDeviceLink
0x3525d000 - 0x3526cfff  GraphicsServices armv6  <af20aba0ec96e7b7c42bb55ac763c784> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x3526d000 - 0x352b0fff  SystemConfiguration armv6  <207f362e707871e74a292cfd1ea7893d> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x354cb000 - 0x354d1fff  MobileKeyBag armv6  <2d83bf6a43bab972d77a1a6e0f3b03d2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x3564b000 - 0x3569afff  Security armv6  <cf625b4dc7ea928891313444ef64a7cb> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x357ca000 - 0x35835fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv6  <eccd1d7183e73587b2c0aa5755a19c39> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x35851000 - 0x35885fff  AppSupport armv6  <783e14db9585fd063c0c2a755cd121b6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x358fc000 - 0x35936fff  MobileCoreServices armv6  <beb473ce80390554bb4af21554522286> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x359b9000 - 0x35ccbfff  GeoServices armv6  <570238d025d41838cc888a0b3f28f4b2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x35cdb000 - 0x35d25fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv6  <cfc94cfa17958f2f94c9eff208a7dace> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x35d51000 - 0x35e47fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv6  <9c44d05cc67f1ebabd795903e581724e> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x35e64000 - 0x35f4ffff  CoreFoundation armv6  <ab0eac0ddd5b4ae1bf8541116e3c0bd1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x35f76000 - 0x3606afff  libiconv.2.dylib armv6  <01916d6784f4de8f3746978faae9c5fa> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x360c8000 - 0x360d4fff  WebBookmarks armv6  <5d1eb10d851d0362e304d9d95f016df1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
0x360f0000 - 0x361edfff  JavaScriptCore armv6  <3547c92c1efc0522b087e7f10eba7728> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x361ee000 - 0x361fbfff  MobileBluetooth armv6  <2b68516e1321011a4efbee2947d463c6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileBluetooth.framework/MobileBluetooth
0x366e5000 - 0x3674dfff  GMM armv6  <adcdfedd491ac237b385b6c2d7f684e3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GMM.framework/GMM
0x36752000 - 0x36771fff  Bom armv6  <f41bef81e23e2bff59155e5ce46762d3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x36826000 - 0x36830fff  AggregateDictionary armv6  <f7429444c955e4f13c6761d20032ab52> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x36849000 - 0x36850fff  liblockdown.dylib armv6  <f470dea180ddf23886df75eb256d3888> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x3686a000 - 0x3686dfff  ActorKit armv6  <d3ec50b4a7f0257ef31baf37936dc275> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ActorKit.framework/ActorKit
0x3689d000 - 0x368cbfff  MIME armv6  <fac8f55c508ff476e07894af7abdb761> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME
0x368cc000 - 0x3711bfff  WebCore armv6  <aa3b6827f051da7a3494c9bee4ebe290> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x3713e000 - 0x3714cfff  libz.1.dylib armv6  <84592e96bae1a661374b0f9a5d03a3a0> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x3714d000 - 0x3718dfff  QuickLook armv6  <54400e0d48ec86c84e937e55790b9e54> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x3718e000 - 0x371dcfff  CoreText armv6  <16c9582fdffb598178287c6ce9fd6897> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x371dd000 - 0x371eefff  DataAccessExpress armv6  <c112bd2791eb706526db25407ec117d4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x371ef000 - 0x3722dfff  ContentIndex armv6  <7f3334380acc72292571803f0b490189> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
0x37378000 - 0x373defff  libBLAS.dylib armv6  <11a3677a08175a30df1b3d66d7e0951a> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x373df000 - 0x37436fff  CoreMedia armv6  <cd5e9398c161f129146931e888e1c92e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x3757d000 - 0x375a7fff  PrintKit armv6  <74f9710fa01a33b5bb04c4aeabd6be7d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x3777f000 - 0x37840fff  ImageIO armv6  <0c1b6f466667ff345f2399d8142a9d10> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x3784c000 - 0x37878fff  DataAccess armv6  <8c045822d57a369835f5b40653a48838> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
0x378b3000 - 0x3791bfff  libvDSP.dylib armv6  <9d264733fc675943c082bd3b9b567b59> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x3791c000 - 0x379a5fff  Message armv6  <9ed4944d998f99e69ba81afdda659bee> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message
0x379c9000 - 0x37a11fff  iCalendar armv6  <fbb717874ea0ede24454a5def644ab69> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
0x37a1f000 - 0x37a31fff  libbsm.0.dylib armv6  <51e7bb18da9afa44a33e54e42fbd0707> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
```

Comment: What is the NSLog statement it's crashing on? And, how come your crash log isn't symbolicated? (Aren't you just running tethered with Xcode?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read this document here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2151/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008184

Basically when you build your project for App Store Distribution, you need to archive the project and also maintain a file containing your project's symbols.  Doing this allows you to take a crash report (like the one you posted) and load it into your project and see the stack at the time of the crash as well as the exact line of code that caused the crash.